# my mail won't show after upgrading to 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, email, stock-email-app

After upgrading my Samsung galaxy s2 to android version 4.0.4 my mail won't show in the default mail app (cant find out the name!). I only get a dropdown bar -- but when I clicked it, the arrow points below, but it doesn't "dropdown" ;(

How can I get my mail shown?

Here is a screen-shot of my mail app.

[image: mail-app]

Comment: Where do you expect you mail to be shown? What place are you talking about? Please update your question so one can follow your steps -- without that information it is hard to help.

Comment: I updated my question....

Comment: Yepp, that should fit. Now people owning an SGS2 could look it up. "Default mail app" is precise enough, if you mean the one that comes pre-installed.

Comment: Yes, the pre installed mail app...

Comment: Does anyone knows how to fix this, or do i have to wait till the next update arrives to my s2?

Comment: I deleted my @Hotmail account, and then re-added it, but still the same problem!?.... HELP?!!!

Comment: Update to latest Jelly Bean

Comment: @Peter Not yet available. for Samsung Galax2 S2.

Comment: @blade19899: For GT-I9100 (international version) it is. Also did you do a full wipe when jumping from GB to ICS?

Comment: @Peter No, i haven't wiped this phone, since i got it.

Comment: Have tried to `clear data` and `clear defaults` on the application menu?

Answer (score -1):

When chaging Android major versions, GB to ICS or ICS to JB or even GB to JB, its advised to do a **full wipe**, since many old files from the previous version might collide with the new Android version.

Since you haven't done it, I suggest you do the following:

1. Backup all your phone's data with either *Titanium Backup* or a *Nandroid backup* if you have a custom recovery installed.
2. Get your phone to *recovery mode* and wipe all data (factory reset). If you have a custom recovery you can wipe `/system`, `/data` and `/cache`.
3. Once clean, reboot in *download mode* and use Odin to update to 4.0.4 (or 4.1.2 if you have the international version GT-I9100)
4. Reboot and enjoy a clean installation of ICS/JB.

Comment: Don't assume that the person posing the question is rooted, and don't form your answer accordingly. As the question is posed, your answer should detail how to do this in Samsungs official application for backups and upgrades.